# Shared classes for Android and Spring MVC projects

Tags: android, eclipse, spring, maven

I've a client-side Android project and a server side Spring MVC project. Some classes defining rest messages exchanged between client and server are common, and could be useful to define a common project to share the classes.
For now I duplicated all the classes in both projects. Client-side classes use Android library (principally Parcelable) and others like jackson for JSON and simpleframework for XML. Server-side classes use Jackson for Json, JAXB for XML and Hibernate for ORM.
I know about how to import these classes in Android Project, it simply need to include hibernate annotation and others in the android libraries, but i'm a little confused about importing an Android project in Spring MVC.
How i have to define this shared project: as a normal Java project, as an Android project? And it's correct/possible to import the Android library in a Spring project or there will be conflicts with the Java library? How to solve?
As last possibility I'm considering to remove the Android dependency substituting Parcelable with Serializable, but I prefer to use Parcelable for its better performances.
I'm using Eclipse Spring Tool Suite with Android Development Tool plugin and Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including the android project in a Spring MVC project doesnt make sense

You should build a standalone standard java project (that compiles and is built to a JAR file) that contains all the code that is shared between the android and springmvc project.

This common JAR file should then be included in both the android project and Spring MVC project. Pretty simple really :)

If you are using Maven you can include it as a dependency (Which will be the cleanest approach) if not then just manually include the JAR in each of the projects.

Comment: But what if the shared code refer some Android feature (eg. some classes implement `android.os.Parcelable`)? Then the jar refers to Android library and it could not be included in Spring MVC project without Android library..

Comment: If you want to use that class in a SpringMVC app then it shouldnt use Android classes as you wont include the android libraries in the MVC app. You could aways instead create an interface for the class in the shared project and then a different implementation for the class in each application. That way you can call it by the interface but the underlying implementation can use Serializable or Parcelable or whatever

Comment: It will be easier Just to use Serializable though if that is an option. Its unlikely to cause noticeable performance issues. Though admittedly I dont know much about the Parcelable interface you refer to

Comment: Assuming I switch to Serializable, how do I to manage dependencies from libraries like Hibernate and Jackson in Eclipse and in Hibernate?  They must be present in Spring MVC and Android projects' pom.xml? Or they must appear only in the shared library's pom and they will be imported in a transitive way?

Comment: Either way would work. You can add them in the shared library pom and they can be included as a transitive dependency. Or, you define the dependency as <scope>provided</scope> in the shared library and then include the dependency in the android and spring mvc pom. The benefit of that approach is you can use different versions of the dependencies in each application if required.

Comment: Ok i created a test version of the shared library and I added it to the java build bath of the Android project and of the Spring project. I also manven-istalled the shared project and added it to maven dependencies of both projects. Initially all worked fine. However after managing some (other) maven dependencies in Android project, and rebooting Eclipse, the shared library's classes are missing in the Android project. Many times tried to re-add the library to java build path and clean the project but they are still missing. Do you know what could cause this?

Comment: I can also use auto-completion to import the shared classes, but after re-adding the imports i get an `the import *** cannot be resolved` error

Comment: Usual eclipse issues.. re-clean all projects and re-set java compiler compliance level solved all problems.